# Как сделать вывод дочерних ресурсов с pdoTools?

Tags: modx, pdotools

Как сделать вывод дочерних ресурсов по определенному шаблону?

С ModX столкнулась впервые, даже близко не понимаю как это делается.

Ресурсы:

Новости:

- Новость1
- Новость2
- Новость3

У каждого дочернего ресурса есть дополнительное поле image (в нем хранится url картинки)

Надо с использованием pdoTools вывести их по шаблону:

```
<h2>Название ресурса</h2>
<a href="ссылка на ресурс"><img src="адрес картинки" alt="название ресурса"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[pdoResources?
                                &parents=`123`
                                &depth=`1`
                                &tpl=`newsItemTpl`
                                &limit=`100`
                                &tvPrefix=``
                                &sortby=`publishedon`
                                &sortdir=`DESC`
                                &templates=`456`
                                &includeContent=`1`
                                &tvPrefix=``
                                &includeTVs=`image`
                            ]]
```

где 456 - ID шаблона новости, 123 - ID родителя "Новости"

newsItemTpl:

```
<h2>[[+pagetitle]]</h2>
<a href="[[+uri]]"><img src="[[+image]]" alt="[[+pagetitle]]"></a>
```